# How to charge an android device with a buck converter

Tags: buck, charger, android

I've got a male micro USB connector like this one

[image]

I'm feeding the output of a buck converter set at 5V to pin 1 positive and pin 5 negative. Remaining pins are not connected. When I plug the connector in, the screen turns black and only the back and menu (or whatever it is) buttons are still lit but do nothing. After disconnecting the cable the phone remains like this for ~15 minutes and resets to normal.

If I plug in an ordinary charger the phone charges without a problem.

I have not done anything to the phone it's a stock android device.

It probably expects something on the not connected pins? I found that some chargers may put resistance between the data pins to indicate available current rate but is not standard so it should not be mandatory..

What do I need to do so I can charge the phone with the minimum 500mA?

## EDIT:

I shorted the data pins as per USB 2 standard for a dedicated charging port and the screen phenomenon now happens only every other try.

After connecting, switching the power supply on and off does not cause the freeze but when off current is drawn from the phone.

Increasing the voltage to 5.25V resulted in ~125mA flowing to the device but without any indication of charging on the screen.

Comment: If you could specify the model of your phone, we could search for the info on what it expects on its data pins in order to charge at a larger current.

Comment: @EdinFifić it is a nokia 6

Answer (score 1):

Measure the current draw. My guess is you're only getting ~100mA. You could try shorting the USB data pins, as that is the USB 2.0 standard for a dedicated charge port. However, you know what they say about standards. Not all phone manufacturers will recognize a DCP, and worse, others expect some other weirdness (looking at your Apple and Samsung) on the data pins to fast charge.

Comment: What is a possible reason for that? Its a 3A (rated, more like 1.5A) buck converter and there is nothing else connected.

Comment: The phone does not know it can draw over 100mA even if you are able to provide 10A. Unless you do something with the data pins so it knows it can draw more.

Comment: @php_nub_qq The buck converter rating is irrelevant. The charge current is controlled by a battery management IC, or possibly the main SOC depending on the phone. Regardless, this all happens inside the phone and you can't control it other than emulating whatever behavior is expected on the data pins.

Comment: I just measured it. Unfortunately I dont have an oscilloscope to give more detailed information though. My multimeter reads 1.45A for like half a second or something and then the screen turns black as described and there is no longer current flowing

Comment: I also shorted the data pins and the screen no longer turns off. It starts charging for a fraction of a second and then stops, after trying this about 5 times it reverted to the old behavior.

Comment: Something else I observe, if I turn off the power supply while everything is connected the flow reverses and there are 80mA going to my buck converter which has an LED and it keeps glowing. When I turn the supply back on current comes back to 0. I also notice that no matter how many times I do that the screen does not go black. It appears to do so only when physically connecting the micro usb. Also I tried increasing the voltage up to 5.25 and I saw that there are 125mA flowing to the phone but there was no indication that the battery is charging which smells like trouble to me so I seized it.

Comment: @php_nub_qq Based on your description, it's probably wired backwards.

Comment: @MattYoung I was too hoping that was the case so I triple checked it and it is not :( I also checked the charger that I have that the phone is happily charging with and it seems to have the data pins shorted with no resistance, I'm really confused at this point.

Comment: @php You really need to get your hands on a score scope and look at 5V through this. It sounds like the buck converter is dropping out but there's no way to do much more without getting the full picture of what's going on.

Comment: @MattYoung I also suspected that so I switched the supply to an old pc psu and got 5v off of there just to test, still the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Well, given all the information in comments and edited in the answer, nothing seemed to work.

I modified an USB cable in such manner, using a proper charger

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZRm8H.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

And it still refused to charge. I tried adding some resistance - 47, 100, 200 ohm, still nothing.

So in the end I bought a charger like this one

[image]

to which I added a fuse and a power transistor and I skipped the buck converter altogether.

I'm not going to accept this as it's not an answer to the original question but is a workaround that worked for me.